# Visual Studio Debug Single Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I use to be able to right-click in one of my test classes and select Debug Test which would run the single test. All of a sudden it says Debug Test(s) when I right-click and runs all my tests.

How can I debug just one test?

Thanks

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: .. have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click directly on your `[TestMethod]` and select "Run test(s)"/"Debug test(s)", or open the **Test Explorer** window (from the menu: Test -> Windows -> Test Explorer) and run test method from there (selecting a group or a single one).

PS: remember to put at least one breakpoint inside the test you want to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but I had to reinstall the NuGet Test packages and that seemed to fix it. Thanks Manuel for the help.